# Automatic Cell resizing does not work with Storyboard

Tags: ios

> I'm trying to setup correctly a self-sizing tableview cell using
>   storyboard. I'm using stackViews embedding two labels and one
>   imageView, everything seems to be correctly set, all the constraints
>   in place, no warnings popped-out, but when the cell row height's box
>   is checked, it gets smaller, to 44px default value, the problem is
>   that it does not estimate a new rowHight and as result just part of
>   the contents (image and half of first label) is displayed. It might be
>   a very dumb question for y'all most experienced on the IOS, but I cant
>   understand what went wrong. I've share some pictures. Thanks in
>   advance.
>           [Image of the App running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMFmy.png): As seen, rows get squashed between them, really ugly.

- [storyboard Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P43o.png)
     [storyboard Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzMSr.png)
     [storyboard Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCgRZ.png)

Comment: None of the screen shots shows you actually running the app. Until you do that, you have no way to know if your self sizing cells are working or not.

Comment: Matt, thanks for your quick feedback, I have edited the question by uploading a pic of the App running. It's not pretty at all. By the way, I figured out how to keep the right size when checking the  automatic rowHeight box, I added to the bottom two constraints, 1. "Equal" and 2. "Less Than or Equal", and it did not get smaller anymore, but still, as you can see from the picture uploaded, results is not pretty. Thanks who could help!